# networkx 2.1 has requirement decorator>=4.1.0, but you'll have decorator 4.0.11 which is incompatible

Tags: python, instagram-api

While running `pip install InstagramAPI` I have 2 errors that I didn't manage to fix yet.

The first error I have is

> "networkx 2.1 has requirement decorator>=4.1.0, but you'll have decorator 4.0.11 which is incompatible"

I tried to run manually `pip install decorator` but the version 4.0.11 is indeed installed and not version 4.1.0.

The second error i receive is:

> "Cannot uninstall 'imageio'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall."

Comment: `pip install decorator --upgrade`

Comment: Thank you @valentin Lorentz.

Comment: Even if I can get rid of Error1, I still get "Cannot uninstall 'imageio'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall" :-(

Comment: `rm -rf <PREFIX>/lib/python*/*-packages/imageio*` usually works

Comment: It worked for me:

pip install --ignore-installed six
or more generally
pip install --ignore-installed ${PACKAGE_NAME}

Answer (score 0):

I would use a virtual environment (the python package) It should take care of most of these dependency problems.

Comment: Thank you @C. Dautermann . By any chance have you come across a recent Python API for Instagram? I have not unfortunately. I'd like to backup all my pictures, posts and DM at once

Comment: Unfortunately not I have also been looking for one. There is a pretty good nodejs API though